# jquery change image src on click, and revert to original image on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

Long time lurker.. first post.

I'm looking to make a play/pause button that animates on hover,
and that changes from 'play' to 'pause' button on click.
(I'm using it to trigger an audiofile)

i have this working by stacking two different coloured images and have a transition in CSS (opacity) on mouse over.

I have been struggling to change the src on click in javascript/jquery, which i managed to get to work (play button turns into pause button, css transition still functional) but i have no clue how to make a conditional if/then statement to have it revert back to the original 'play' button images on the next click.

I've tried quite a few things and feel that i'm close, but since i have little to no experience in javascript/jquery, I have no clue how to proceed.

I hope that my question is somewhat understandable and I'd very much appreciate any help i can get!

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
  $("#playpause").click(function() {
    $("#top").attr("src", "//placehold.it/100?text=play");
    $("#bottom").attr("src", "//placehold.it/100?text=pause");
  });
});
```

```css
#playpause {
  position: relative;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  margin: 5px 10px 0 0;
}

#playpause img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.7s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}

#playpause img.top:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="playpause" class="one column">
  <a id="flytonight" href="#">

    <img class="bottom" id="bottom" src="//placehold.it/100?text=play" />
    <img class="top" id="top" src="//placehold.it/100?text=pause" />

  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You just need to set a variable outside of your click handler called "clicked" or something. Make it initially false. Then inside the click handler, check if it exists or not with an if statement, put your logic inside that if/else block. In each conditional block, reverse the value of that variable after you've done your image swapping. I'd give you a code example but I'm on mobile. Is that helpful enough as a starting block?

Comment: You could store the previous value in another attribute, and flip the two on click.

Comment: Also when I say variable, that can either be a standard JS one like `var clicked = false` or you can use a data attribute on the element itself to keep it more closely scoped, especially if you have multiple buttons. That would be best achieved by looping through each element with `$(".element").each()` and then targeting the element in the loop with `$(this)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to check the current `src` attribute in each `click`, and change it accordingly. You will be always switching between the two `src` values.

```
$("document").ready(function() {
  $("#playpause img").click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("src") === "//placehold.it/100?text=play")
      $(this).attr("src", "//placehold.it/100?text=pause");
    else if ($(this).attr("src") === "//placehold.it/100?text=pause")
      $(this).attr("src", "//placehold.it/100?text=play");
  });
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
  $("#playpause img").click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("src") === "//placehold.it/100?text=play")
      $(this).attr("src", "//placehold.it/100?text=pause");
    else if ($(this).attr("src") === "//placehold.it/100?text=pause")
      $(this).attr("src", "//placehold.it/100?text=play");
  });
});
```

```css
#playpause {
  position: relative;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  margin: 5px 10px 0 0;
}

#playpause img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.7s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="playpause" class="one column">
  <a id="flytonight" href="#">
    <img class="bottom" id="bottom" src="//placehold.it/100?text=play" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your suggestion, I've edited and added the images that i'm using, still have trouble getting to switch both images from 'play' to 'pause' on click at the same time. This causes the wrong 'bottom' image to show. ( see example).. happy thanksgiving.. if you're in that part of the world!

Comment: @Sander You need to remove the `:hover` from your css and make sure that the two images aren't overlapping.

Comment: I have the images stacked on top of each other (a red playbutton and a white play button on top) and use the `:hover` to get the top image opacity to zero, showing the lower of the two images. When i implement your solution, it works fine for the top image, on click it changes into a white pausebutton and returns to a white playbutton on the next click. the bottom image however is still a red playbutton and also needs to change to a red pausebutton when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I did not pay enough attention to your question, this would be a solution:

```
var playToggle = false;
    $("#playpause").click(function() {
            if (playToggle === true){
               $("#top").attr("src", "//placehold.it/100?text=play");
               $("#bottom").attr("src", "//placehold.it/100?text=pause");
            else{
               $("#bottom").attr("src", "//placehold.it/100?text=play");
               $("#top").attr("src", "//placehold.it/100?text=pause");
            }
        playToggle = !playToggle;
      });
```